# Fasting blood sugar cause and effect relationship with Atrial Fibrillation

Tags: type-2-diabetes, blood-sugar

NOTE: If there is a better-suited forum for this question, please migrate.

There are academic articles on elevated blood sugar's possible impact on the heart muscle lending to a tendency toward atrial fibrillation events, however what I'm looking for is data on the reverse, specifically if a (temporary) elevated fasting blood glucose can be caused by a AFIB episode.

Comment: This is the right place for the question but a link to and a pertinent quote from those articles you mention sure would improve it.

Comment: @Carey, OK here's a link (with several internal references) https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/CIRCEP.119.007351.. BUT.... understand I am looking for data (reports/articles) that support the notion that an incident of AFIB might cause sufficient stress to temporarily increase a person's blood glucose.

Comment: What I was suggesting was adding it to your question, not just replying to me in comments.